# Angular2 router appends component instead of replacing it

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an Angular2 application with one router outlet that displays different components depending on which link is clicked in a side menu.

The markup for the main component containing the `<router-outlet>` looks like this

```
<div *ngIf="authenticated == false">
  <app-login></app-login>
</div>
<div *ngIf="authenticated">
  <div class="page home-page">
    <header class="header">
      <app-navbar></app-navbar>
    </header>
    <div class="page-content d-flex align-items-stretch">
      <div class="sidebar-container">
        <app-sidebar-menu></app-sidebar-menu>
      </div>
      <div class="content-inner">
      <app-page-header></app-page-header>
        <div id="sub-content">
          <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I click the *Demo* link, the demo component is rendered, but if I then click the *Home* link, the home component is rendered above the demo component in DOM. Clicking them a few times will result with a DOM like this

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="" id="sub-content">
    <router-outlet _ngcontent-c0=""></router-outlet>
  <app-home _nghost-c6="">...</app-home>
  <app-demo _nghost-c7="">...</app-demo>
  <app-home _nghost-c6="">...</app-home> <!-- Why so many here? Should be just either one <app-home> or <app-demo>  -->
  <app-demo _nghost-c7="">...</app-demo>
  <app-home _nghost-c6="">...</app-home>
  <app-demo _nghost-c7="">...</app-demo>
  <app-footer _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c5="">...</app-footer>
</div>
```

The routes are defined as

```
export const router: Routes = [
    { path: 'demo', component: DemoComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] }
]
```

How come that the `<router-outlet>` doesn't replace the component, but instead adds another "instance" of the component when switching between the routes?

Comment: Wow ... it certainly shouldn't be doing that. It correctly replaces the content in my apps using similar code. Can you do a plunker that reproduces the error? Or provide the html for the home component in your question above?

Comment: Thought I was going crazy! I'm working on a plunker!

Comment: This is also happening to me in a custom tabs component. I've had a few people look over it with me and I can't find a thing. I thought that I might have an *ngFor hanging out somewhere that was somehow creating divs for each click, but that isn't the issue. If I inspect the code in browser it shows the router link directly followed by a list of components that is added to on each click. Hope someone can find an answer soon.

Comment: Interesting, I'm not able to replicate it in a Plunker, it behaves just as it should. I'll look for an *ngFor, that's something I hadn't thought of! Will keep you updated!

Comment: Just a quick thought, are you using firebase? This happened just after I implemented firebase in my app.

Comment: Yep, Firebase and AngularFire2!

Comment: Hmm. Maybe it is making some kind of change to the router outlet.

Comment: Update. This also adds all modals to the bottom of the page (I'm using angular material modals) in the same place as my tab content.

Comment: I just solved mine. I was using the asynchronous pipe on an element contained inside of one of my tabs. I removed the pipe and now it is working again.

Comment: Interesting! I have an `| async` aswell, but removing it does nothing for me except breaking my other functionality! :(

Comment: Hmmm... Well, good luck. I know mine seemed to be caused by an error with | async. Maybe resolve any console errors and see if that helps. I'll make sure to post here if I find a definite answer.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

By using the method of elimination, I found out that the culprit of the issue was the `BrowserAnimations` module in my `app.module.ts`. By removing it from my `imports` it the problem went away. I'll look into creating a Plunker to demonstrate it.

**Update:**
This is described in this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19093).

**Update 2017-12-13:**
This has now been fixed with this PR, [fix(animations): properly recover and cleanup DOM when CD failures occur](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/20719).

Comment: Thank you for clarification, this has been the most important message I have read the whole day! You rock.

Comment: Glad it helped you! I've tried to recreate it with a Plunkr without any success to be able to find out if it's a bug or not!

Comment: This is also not solving the problem, very strange !

Comment: This is a known Angular issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19093  

Until this is fixed you have to identify and isolate the exception as TetraDev suggested.

Comment: [Master branch commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/46aa0a1cf689e98ee37c9be488431fe48b3608a8) for the fix.

Comment: Removing BrowserAnimations had temporarily fixed my problem but it didn't add up. I never had console errors. It turned out to be an issue with my route guard. canActivate returned/resolved a promise in a way Angular didn't like. I improved the logic and suddenly the issue is gone

Comment: I am having same issue, I am using Angular 8.1.3. Please take a look my stackblitz. I am able to reproduce there. I am not using BrowserAnimationsModule.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a8lmjs

Comment: @GeetT your stackblitz is correct though. You have the router outlet in your `app.component.html` and it shows everything in that template and components you navigate to. [I forked your StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8kqvyb) with an example that shows it works as expected.

Answer (score 26):

This happens also when **component A is throwing an error**, so when navigating to Component B, Component A could not be destroyed due to the error. This is a bug with Angular. Until they fix, find the cause of the error being thrown and fix it. Check your dev tools console.

Comment: In my case, it was a parent component that contained an error (that look harmless at first sight) and apparently was causing the APPENDING instead of REPLACING. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks. it helped. In my case, it was happening if either of the components had an error!

Comment: Thanks! I was facing the same issue and there was no error in console when I navigate to component B. This issue may come when you do not see any errors on the console as well. In my case fix was as follows:   Original Code: this.obj1 = obj2;                                   Fixed Code: this.obj1 = _.extend(this.obj1, obj2);

Comment: I'm having this issue as well. I don't get the appending issue once I remove BrowserAnimationsModule, but now I get an error (Found the synthetic listener @inOut.done.) because I don't have BrowserAnimationsModule!

Comment: Yea, I realize now that I need BrowserAnimationsModule for my Toastr stuff. Any thoughts on how to get around this without removing that module?

Answer (score 7):

I had a very similar issue, also using Firebase.

[See the components being appended to router outlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDKny.gif)

However, I found that the issue was coming from an error within one of my components, not related to my routing. One of the components had a reference to a "FormsArray", which was not used and malformed. It threw errors in the devtools console, but I didn't think of checking there, since everything was compiling fine.

Not sure if that will help anybody.

Comment: It actually helped me! My problem was that a new child component failed to render completely (use date pipe for wrong data). In this scenarion angular was showing partial data for new component and old component - one after another. As soon as I fixed the pipe issue the problem solved. Thanks a lot for this hint!

Comment: How did you debug.? I'm getting the same issue.! , can you show code changes which you made.!

Comment: I have the same problem as @Mrworldwide. This is one of the things I don't like about using frameworks, it's impossible to debug sometimes.

Answer (score 3):

I was using NgZone inside the component and my routerLink was having the same issue, without any errors inside console.

Changed the routerLink to a (click) inside  and called a function like this:

```
constructor(
    (...)
    private zone: NgZone,
    (...)
  ) { }

goToPage() {
    this.zone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/page']));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue , and the reason was that i used a directive that is not declared in component A and there was no error in compile or console.
so when navigate to component B the router was appending the content.

To debug I commented out all the html markup in both components leaving only a h1 to see if the content was appending. with some tests i found the directive and by removing it, router back to normal again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this matches your situation exactly, however I have had previous Components append to the DOM when trying to load a different route, and finally I figured that the use of `Hash` was conflicting with addresses of the component,

> export const AppRouting = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { **useHash: false** });

This fixed all my problems with unwanted appended components