# How to redirect correctly in a global error handler

Tags: angular, error-handling, angular-ui-router

I have this global error handler:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    @Injectable()
    export class GlobalErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler  
    {
        constructor(private injector: Injector) {
            super(false);
        }

        handleError(error) {
            super.handleError(error);
            const router = this.injector.get(Router);
                router.navigateByUrl('/error');
        }

    }
```

I put it in app.module:

```
  providers: [
    {
      provide: ErrorHandler, 
      useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
    }
  ]
```

to test this I throw an error inside a service. For some reason the error component shows up *together* with the other contents of the page. Something like this:

if I test the error component by going to /error it shows up like this (the error page is a paragraph with a single line):

```
Sorry, something went wrong!
```

but when I go to my home page where the error should trigger it shows up like this:

```
Sorry, something went wrong!

....
... Original content for /home
....

Sorry, something went wrong!
```

Can someone enlighten me what am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I've updated to angular-cli 1.5.2 AND also updated to angular 5 and the bug seems fixed there. I can navigate to the error page using the router.

Comment: Do you have any error in the browser console?

Comment: Only the one I am generating

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've made some research and here is the reason why it behaves this way:

Since you're throwing an error in your service, the component which is using the service **cannot be destroyed**, thus the router is not able to release it. Thanks [@TetraDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5376813/tetradev) for [pointing this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46816263/1199711).

While someone might think it's an Angular bug I cannot confirm because I haven't found an open issue regarding it (feel free to update the answer if you have the link).

In order to resolve your problem I suggest not to use `Router` in this case and perform a browser redirect `window.location.href = '/error';` instead.

Comment: Thank you, this just saved me. I would have spent days trying to figure this one out, I'm pretty new to Angular.

Answer (score -1):

It depends in where you have placed the router-outlet. if you something like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<!-- Home Component Content -->
```

It will loads just like you say, with the other components content. To avoid this behavior you have to struct your main component like this:

```
<router-outlet></router-outle>
```

Just that and the things you want in all pages, including the error one.

Comment: No, both /home and /error should be *inside* the router outlet and only *one* of them at a time not both, like in my case

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. Plus these two blocks of code are literally identical - except you mispelled `router-outlet` in the last one.

Comment: Just a note. Component that you routes to will be placed **AFTER** `<router-outlet></router-outlet>`, not **inside**.