# Angular router appends component data instead of replacing the component

Tags: ajax, angular, routes, components, angular4-router

First of all i tried with this answers but not found my solution:  [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622453/angular2-router-appends-component-instead-of-replacing-it)

Let me expalin how i implemented:

1. I have two components 
   `forgot-password` & `new-password`
2. When the user submit forgot password form he will get a `email verification link`.
3. when user clicks that email `link`
4. it will go to **forgot-password.ts** file and then in `ngOnInit` `ajax` call will go.
5. From ajax response if **success** data it will redirect to the **new-password**

**or**

6. it will throw the **error** in frogot password page itself

**My issue:**
when I try to navigate to new-password from forgot-password **ts** file after ajax response  using the external link (`Gmail` link) ; it
appends component data instead of replacing the **forgot** with **new** component.

My **app.moduel.ts**:

```
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
   BrowserAnimationsModule,
})
```

**And this my route code  forgot-password.ts** :

```
if(result.data == "failure")    {
// failure no data
}
else {
// success data
this._router.navigate(['new-password']);
}
```

**NOTE**

1. When I comment these `BrowserAnimationsModule` in my
   **app.module.ts**  the routing is working fine.**But** I need this`BrowserAnimationsModule`.! what is the alternate solution.
2. If not form external link(Gmail) the `routing` is working fine.

Comment: can u pls post ur routing file and the ajax call from where u route to `new-password` page

Comment: Did you find a solution to the problem? I'm trying to fix this issue in my app for about two weeks with no luck

Comment: Yes.!! when there is an error in your component `A` or `B`  this issue is coming..! Luckily my error displayed in the `console` which is `touched undefined ` so I found alternate to that error(fixed error). try to find the error in both `typescript` files you will find the solution.ATB

Answer (score 4):

Update to lastest version of Angular

Also, try :

```
 if(result.data == "failure")    {
    // failure no data
 }
 else {
   // success data
   this.zone.run(() =>{
      this._router.navigate(['new-password']);
   });
 }
```

Comment: I have already tried with `zone` and `set time`, but it's not working, anyway, i found the solution I will update my answer soon.

Comment: Using 'zone' worked more me in angular 6. Can someone point me the relation between BrowserAnimationModule and zone. I've found this: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19093 but clueless.

Answer (score 1):

For me

```
setTimeout(() => {
   this.router.navigate(['']);
}, 0);
```

did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Instead of navigating to new-password from forgot-password ts file,you can give the route link of your new password page in your `email verification link`,and in constructor of new password component you can use your ajax call,on success of that open new password page and in error case navigate to the error page.

Comment: The `new-password` page holds very sensitive data until unless the email link is true then only it should go.!   `else` it should stop @forgot.           `Secondly like you said` if I check code new new-password page on failure it should redirect to @forgot hence both are same; issue cant fix with that

Comment: You can use *ngif in the same new password page ,and in the error case redirect to the error page.

Comment: there is no error page...!!!!!! i think you will not understand my point