# Angular 5 Component not removed on child route changed

Tags: angular, angular5, parent-child, angular-routing, metronic

Hey i have a problem with my Angular 5 App. Ive created a simple app with some component routing. The routing looks like:

```
{ path: '', component: SetupComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }, // here we can add a landingpage
{ path: 'setup', component: SetupComponent },
{
    path: 'lan/:reference', component: LanComponent, // use special layout here which is defined in LanComponent
    children: [
        { path: '', redirectTo: 'dashboard', pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
        { path: 'attendees', component: AttendeesComponent },
        { path: 'games', component: GamesComponent },
        { path: 'royal-beefs', component: RoyalBeefsComponent },
    ]
},
{path: '**', component: SetupComponent}
```

The routing runs like a charm but if i am switching between these child routes the old child is not removed from dom.

[image]

If i am switching between the root routes everything works. If i am making the child routes to absolute routes it is also working.

index.html

```
<body class="m-page--fluid m--skin- m-content--skin-light2 m-header--fixed m-header--fixed-mobile m-aside-left--enabled m-aside-left--skin-dark m-aside-left--offcanvas m-footer--push m-aside--offcanvas-default">
<div class="m-grid m-grid--hor m-grid--root m-page">
  <app-root></app-root> <!-- app.component.ts -->
</div>
</body>
```

app.component.html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

lan.component.html

```
<app-header-nav></app-header-nav>
<!-- begin::Body -->
<div class="m-grid__item m-grid__item--fluid m-grid m-body">
  <div class="m-grid__item m-grid__item--fluid m-wrapper">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- end:: Body -->
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

in the games.component.html and the others there is only the content.
The links will be generated with routerLink like:

```
[routerLink]="['/lan', params.reference, 'dashboard']"
[routerLink]="['/lan', params.reference, 'attendees']"
```

As a hint: ive developed this application first without any complex design. Everything works. Now i wanted to integrate Metronic Dashboard Theme and i am getting this problem.
If anyone has a solution, please post it :)

UPDATE:
Here are some links to the theme:

https://keenthemes.com/metronic/documentation.html

https://keenthemes.com/metronic/preview/?demo=demo12

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 router appends component instead of replacing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622453/angular2-router-appends-component-instead-of-replacing-it)

Comment: Yeah i saw that question too. Ive had not tested every solution but im on it.

Comment: The main point is that there probably is a silent error somewhere that causes the renderer to hang! :(

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer!
in my html files i had a directive unwraptag. The template needed this.
i removed it and everything works fine. In the directive file the selector was marked as eslint error. This was the selector: '[appunwraptag]',