# Angular2 site showing odd behavior after error

Tags: angular, error-handling

I'm not really sure how to describe this in a few words, so sorry for the vague title.

I have an Angular 2 site. When things are working right, it's perfect, but once an error gets thrown, the site stops functioning as expected. For example:

If I click on one link and the subsequent page throws an error, it seems to permanently wreak havoc on my site since, if I try to click away to something else, I go to the new page, but the previous page's content is still visible below (literally below, like a block element, not layered) and if I keep clicking around, I basically start stacking page content. Even if I log out, it doesn't help. I literally need to start over in the location bar and "re-browse" to the homepage to get it to reset itself.

Any idea how I can make the site fail more gracefully than that?

Comment: it's impossible to say what could be the cause. You need to understand where the problem is coming from and post the relevant code.

Comment: Sadly, I have no clue what's causing it. :(

Comment: Heh, I actually found the same issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45622453/angular2-router-appends-component-instead-of-replacing-it and removing BrowserAnimationsModule solved that issue. Unfortunately, I now have another error since I don't have BrowserAnimationsModule included.

Comment: Check app.module.ts file once

Comment: I updated to the latest angular, toastr, etc, and all works fine, now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just posting this as an answer so future people will know what happened. Apparently, I was using an older version of BrowserAnimationsModule which was updated to solve this exact issue in Angular5.

I updated to the latest version of Angular and all was fixed.

Comment: Hi @ReverendBubbles what version of Angular did you updated to in order to fix the bug?

Comment: This was a while ago. I forget if it was 4 or 6.